# VS2019: How to disable the error navigator in the scrollbar?

Tags: visual-studio, visual-studio-2019

[image]

I am trying to hide this error navigator that got introduced in vs2019. I searched the options, but didn't manage to find the correct setting.

**Edit:**
[image]

I am referring to the "No Issues found" view. (The gif is from the official microsoft release)

Comment: where do you see this

Comment: @Sajeetharan At the bottom of the text editor, right next to the horizontal scrollbar.

Comment: that's strange, i do not get to seee. can you post a bigger screen shot

Comment: @Sajeetharan I updated my post.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

You can hide this error navigator aka "No Issues found" in Text Editor general options unchecking **Show file health indicator**:

[image]

Comment: Thank you: those intellisense errors have been plaguing me!